# Serializing Model in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am having trouble serializing my model using `@Html.Raw` in javascript. I basically want to serialise the model so I can pass it through a callback method on the client and then de-serialise it on the server.

```
[Serializable]
public class AdvanceSearch
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

}
```

And in the javascript

```
    var now = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    alert(now.Name);
```

But the alert always comes back as `null` which therefore means it hasn't serialised. Am I missing anything?

Cheers

Comment: `now` is a string (Since you put in in quotes (`""`)). How can it possibly have a `Name` property?

Comment: Argh ok, but if I remove the quotes the javascript doesnt under the razor syntax of @HTML.Raw etc... so how do I convert it if you get what I mean?

Comment: In javascript you'd need to `JSON.parse` to convert the string to a javascript object with a `Name` property. `alert(JSON.parse(now).Name)`

Comment: The default value for a string property will be `null`. Are you sure your model is being populated properly?

Answer (score 0):

By using the Newtonsoft json serializer/deserializer this can be achieved. To serialize your model use as below.

Name space: `Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
var now = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( Model );
```

To deserialize,

```
ViewModel vm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModel>( obj );
```

Here ViewModel is your view model. Hope it helps!